# Check if a record is selected from a dataPointGrid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have a dataPointGrid and I want to check if a record from it is being selected (mouse clicked on)

[image]

Data point grid above. I want to check if a folder (record) is being selected.

Is there a method that does this?

Comment: What is dataPointGrid? Are you talking about `ListGrid`? Share some piece of sample code to get help sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [ListGrid#addSelectionChangedHandler()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#addSelectionChangedHandler%28com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.events.SelectionChangedHandler%29) on list grid that is called when (row-based) selection changes within this grid. Note this method fires for each record for which selection is modified - so when a user clicks inside a grid this method will typically fire twice (once for the old record being deselected, and once for the new record being selected).

Look at the [ListGrid#setSelectionType()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#setSelectionType%28com.smartgwt.client.types.SelectionStyle%29) as well that defines a listGrid's clickable-selection behavior (MULTIPLE, SINGLE, SIMPLE or NONE)